# "Отладчик установлен неправильно" Visual Studio 17

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, отладчик

Здравствуйте. 
Создал новый проект WPF в Студии, покидал нужных виджетов, пытаюсь запустить, получаю ошибку:

```
Ошибка при попытке запуска проекта: не удалось запустить программу 
<путь>
Отладчик установлен неправильно. Запустите программу Setup для установки или 
восстановления отладчика.
```

Запускаю установщик, выбираю **VS17** -> **изменить**. В сводке указанно (если это важно):

- **Включено**

  - Средства разработки классических приложений
  - Средства разработки для .NET 4.6.1
  - C# и Visual Basic
- **Необязательные**

  - Blend for visual studio
  - Инструменты для Entity Framework 6
  - Средства профилирования
  - Поддержка языка F#
  - Средства разработки .NET Core 1.0 - 1.1
- Среда выполнения .NET Core
  Что еще может понадобиться, ума не приложу.

Не могли бы вы подсказать, в чем может быть дело?

---

Попытка переустановить студию приводит к сбою установки со следующей ошибкой (из журнала)

```
Не удалось восстановить пакет "Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist,version=4.6.81.6".
        URL-адрес поиска: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist;PackageAction=Repair;ReturnCode=5100
        Затронутые рабочие нагрузки
            Основной редактор Visual Studio (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)
        Затронутые компоненты
            Основной редактор Visual Studio (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Журнал
            C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170524225231_002_Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.log
        Сведения
            Команда выполнена: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist,version=4.6.81.6\dotNetFx-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /repair /KeepAUPaused /ChainingPackage Visual_Studio_15_Setup /CEIPconsent /log "C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170524225231_002_Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.log"
            Код возврата: 5100
            Сведения о коде возврата: Азия
```

---

По совету @Eikhner обновил windows, установил проблемный пакет руками, перезагрузился; никакого эффекта. Попробовал восстановить студию, получаю сбой. Единственная ошибка, которую пока удалось вынуть из журнала:

```
Не удалось установить перечисленные рабочие нагрузки и компоненты в продукте из-за сбоев в пакете.

Неполные рабочие нагрузки
    Основной редактор Visual Studio (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)

Неполные компоненты
        Основной редактор Visual Studio (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)

Вы можете искать решения по сведениям ниже, изменить выбор рабочих нагрузок и компонентов и повторить установку, или же удалить продукт с компьютера.

Ниже перечислены отдельные сбои в пакете, которые сделали перечисленные выше рабочие нагрузки и компоненты неполными. Чтобы найти имеющиеся отчеты об этих проблемах, скопируйте и вставьте URL-адрес из сообщения о сбое пакета в адресную строку веб-браузера. Если о проблеме уже сообщалось, вы сможете найти решения или обходные пути. В противном случае вы можете создать новую запись о проблеме, в которой другие пользователи смогут найти решения или обходные пути.

Не удалось восстановить пакет "Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist,version=4.6.81.6".
        URL-адрес поиска: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist;PackageAction=Repair;ReturnCode=5100
    Затронутые рабочие нагрузки
        Основной редактор Visual Studio (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)
    Затронутые компоненты
        Основной редактор Visual Studio (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Журнал
        C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170529214845_002_Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.log
    Сведения
        Команда выполнена: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist,version=4.6.81.6\dotNetFx-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /repair /KeepAUPaused /ChainingPackage Visual_Studio_15_Setup /CEIPconsent /log "C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170529214845_002_Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.log"
        Код возврата: 5100
        Сведения о коде возврата: Азия
```

---

@PashaPash, файл, о котором вы говорите, отсутствует, но есть с таким же именем и расширением `.log.html`

```
OS Version = 6.0.6000, SP = 0.0, Platform 2
OS Description = Vista - x64 Ultimate Edition 
MSI = 5.0.7601.23593
Windows version = amd64_windowsfoundation_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_615fdfe2a739474c.manifest
Windows servicing = 6.1.7601.18766
CommandLine = C:\f5fa5e713993e05ed093ae6f7e40\\Setup.exe /q /norestart /repair /KeepAUPaused /ChainingPackage Visual_Studio_15_Setup /CEIPconsent /log "C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170529214845_002_Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.log" /x86 /x64 /redist
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Repairing
Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Setup
Package Version = 4.6.01055
User Experience Data Collection Policy: AlwaysUploaded
Logging all the global blocks


Installation Blockers:

Не удается выполнить установку в режиме совместимости.

Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x000013EC), "A StopBlock was hit or a System Requirement was not met." (Elapsed time: 0 00:00:08).
```

Система почему-то определилась как виста. Что бы это могло означать?

Comment: попробуите проверить обновления , которые есть в вашей системе .
Сначала -KB2919442,
потом KB2919355 , так как второе не ставится без первого,
а нет фраимворк 4.6 не ставится без KB2919355.

Возможно поможет

Comment: как вариант попробовать отдельным установщиком поставить необходимый компонент `Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist` на английском , установить необходимый языковой пакет , и попробовать снова изменить студию ..., если и отдельным установщиком не удастся установить  - тогда уже искать проблему , почему не ставится необходимый софт , возможно какое другое сообщение выдаст , по которому получится что то выяснить .

Comment: @Eikhner, Попробовал обновить винду (последний раз делал это почти год назад, наверное, не лучшая идея), не помогло. Хотя в "журнале обновлений" нет ни KB2919442, ни KB2919355, есть только KB2999226.

Comment: Подождите, KB2919442 это обновление для восьмерки, у меня седьмой windows.

Comment: попробуите накатить пакет отдельным установщиком msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx , получится или нет

Comment: а что при этом в логе проблемного пакета (C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170529214845_002_Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.log)?

Comment: Переустанови Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы создать новый проект WPF в Visual Studio 2017, понадобится компонент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный компонент содержит в себе все необходимое, конечно, можно поставить дополнительные отдельные компоненты, такие как:

- Пакет SDK для .NET Framework 4.6.2
- .NET Framework 4.6.2

Хотя, все что нужно выбирается автоматически и можно вручную выбрать то, чего не хватает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если после обновления операционной системы Windows теперь не удается восстановить среду разработки Visual Studio 2017, то тут можно пойти двумя путями. Пробовать нужно сначала с менее затратного:

- Полностью удалить среду разработки  Visual Studio 2017 со всеми ее вспомогательными элементами. После удаления не забывать перезагрузить компьютер и чистить мусор. Зависимые компоненты тоже удалять. Проверить обновления операционной системы Windows, при наличии - установить. Снова перезагрузить систему. Скачать последнюю версию установщика среды разработки  Visual Studio 2017, запустить инсталлятор и выбрать необходимые рабочие нагрузки (обязательно выбрать *Разработка классических приложений .NET* и новый .NET Framework желательно). Завершить установку, при этом следовать инструкции, снова перегрузиться и пробовать создать новый проект, с нуля. (либо просто удалить и установить заново, но лучше конечно все почистить).

Сначала показалось, что этот метод менее затратный, но по сути он более затратный, чем следующий, который будет предложен. Итак, быстрый и затратный способ сделать так, чтобы заработало:

- Перенести нужные файлы на диск, хранящиеся на диске с системой. Переустановить систему и накатить среду разработки  Visual Studio 2017 с нуля.

---

Да, я предлагаю такой ответ. Увы, если в среде разработки что-то сыпется, после чего она перестает исправно работать - это приводит к большим проблемам. Решать эти проблемы приходится долго и нудно. Устанавливать пакеты, докачивать компоненты, копировать файлы с рабочего компа на свой, выяснять, почему файлы приложения удалены или почему вдруг антивирус что-то заблокировал и удалил. На все это тратится слишком много времени. Если вам не удалось решить этот вопрос за несколько дней, то решение лежит на поверхности, займет всего пару часов.

Сам недавно столкнулся с проблемой в Visual Studio, обновил - она стала глючить, затем перестал запускаться тестовый клиент WCF, затем стала сама перезагружаться. Переустановил среду разработки и все заработало. Как-то ранее при возникновении больших проблем пытался выяснить в чем проблема в среде разработки, но это отнимает слишком много времени.

Тем более, сообщение об ошибке звучит так:

> “Отладчик установлен неправильно”

Значит нужно установить правильно, а для этого, как минимум, нужно его удалить. А удаляется он лучше всего вместе со всей средой разработки Visual Studio. Как-то так.